# PDF integrating by code

Tags: ios, pdf, vector, xcode6

As Apple introduced the PDF support for the Xcode Image Asset Catalog I was wondering if it's also possible to add PDFs at runtime?

What I want is to download my PDF-Assets and use them similar to JPGs or PNGs in my App with the difference that I only need one instead of 3 resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

use this link it will help you

http://alldonegoodbye.tumblr.com/post/97647217699/xcode-6-vector-image-support-pdf

Comment: My problem is to do it at runtime.